# Highcharts: Dynamically change axis on legendItemClick

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to change the size of two yAxis for a Stockchart when a legend is clicked. I've tried this but neither of them work:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function(event) {
                    // does not change the height on the y axis
                    chart.yAxis[0].height = 5; 
                    chart.redraw();

                    // changes the size but throws: 
                    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined 
                    var chartOptions = chart.options;
                    chartOptions.yAxis[0].height = 5; 
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);                                 
                }
            },
        }
    },
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/uvL8f/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [axis.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update) like in the example:

```
$('#up').click(function(){
         chart.yAxis[0].update({
             height:100
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EhRA8/